# Trigger onOpenUrl with specific url programmatically within SwiftUI App

Tags: ios, swiftui, apple-push-notifications, deep-linking, uiapplicationdelegate

#### Circumstances

I've got a SwiftUI App with deep link support. When `.onOpenUrl` is triggered, the app navigates to a specific screen. Every view can listen to that deep link url and therefore has all information to properly set the relevant states (like the `TabView` selecting a specific tab).
I use deep links for Widgets.

Now that my app supports push notifications, I want to use that deep link navigation handling to open a specific screen based on the push notifications `userInfo` that comes from the [according UIApplicationDelegate method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application).

#### Idea

The idea is to generate a deep link url from that user info and pass it down the view hierarchy so that every view can react to `.onOpenUrl` and set state based on the opened push notification. That way I don't have to add an extra `EnvironmentObject` to the environment and listen to `.onChange(of: someUserInfoInsideTheEnvironment)` in every view, duplicating the existing `.onOpenUrl` handling for deep links.

#### Question

Is there a way to manually (programmatically) trigger `.onOpenUrl` with a specific url?
Like setting a specific environment value or -object so that every view in the view hierarchy will call `.onOpenUrl` with my own deep link url?